# jquery 1.4.2 in ie7 adding name attribute as submitName

Tags: jquery

```
var input = $("<input />").attr('id', elementId).attr('name', elementName);
```

I am creating input as above and then adding it to parent.

All browsers working ok

but in ie7 there is no name attribute for above input it creates submitName attribute instead.

And jquery validator do not like when there is no name.

**Why is it changing name of attribute to submitName from name?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weird behaviour of iframe `name` attribute set by jQuery in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105815/weird-behaviour-of-iframe-name-attribute-set-by-jquery-in-ie)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var input = $('<input id="' + elementId + '" name="' + elementName + '" />')
```

Or:

```
var input = $("<input />").attr({
                                 id: elementId,
                                 name: elementName});
```

Comment: The first option works but the second one doesn't as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in IE. You might have to change the way you create the input tag

`var input = $('<input id="' + elementId + '"name="' + name + '"/>');`

http://blogs.ajithbhat.com/2013/07/submitname-issue-while-creating-name.html