# knockoutjs attr binding and IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, knockout.js, attr

This syntax works in FF

```
<input data-bind="checked: isRequest, attr: { name: 'id_' + id }" type="checkbox" />
```

But in IE7 the name attribute isnt rendered?

**edit:**
Other attributes like title works, strange, but i need the name attribute so that i can post the data :/

Comment: You may want to put name in quotes:
<input data-bind="checked: isRequest, attr: { 'name': 'id_' + id }" type="checkbox" />

Comment: didnt work.. BUT even if jQUery or internet explroer dev tools cant see the name attr its there, i can see it when i peek in the request :D

Comment: More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105815/weird-behaviour-of-iframe-name-attribute-set-by-jquery-in-ie

Comment: @Anders, I don't understand -- is it still a problem for you?

Comment: I know sometimes the attribute itself needs to be in quotes, e.g. "attr: { 'name': 'id_' + id }"

Comment: @Anders - You say you can't see the attribute in the IE Dev tools - you know you have to refresh the dev tools after ANY dom update, right? It's not like firebug with it's live update.

Comment: @ Judah Himango No, this is working for me. @Peter LaComb Jr. refresh were not needed for 'title' attribute, so why would it be needed for 'name'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem with trying to be tricky with attr: { 'class': something, 'style': somethingElse} and gave up trying to get the attr binding to work in IE7.

What did work was writing a custom binding to apply jquery manually:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.customCss = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var css = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).addClass(css);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var css = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
       $(element).addClass(css);
    }
};
```

So in your case I would try adding the following to your document.ready before ko.applyBindings():

```
ko.bindingHandlers.customName= {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var name= ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).attr('name', 'id_' + name);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var name= ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).attr('name', 'id_' + name);
    }
};
```

then bind your input as:

```
<input data-bind="checked: isRequest, customName: id }" type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: in IE7 you have to bind against the 'className' attribute not the 'class' attribute, but browser difference should not be the work of the view model so a custom binding is a good way to abstract away the broswer knowledge to jQuery

Comment: Im marking this as answer, but addClass is not always optimum in a MVVM case, checkout this fiddle for a soltion using removeClass before addClass http://jsfiddle.net/eZRQb/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I have found a workaround to the IE6/7 problem. The solution was found by looking at the latest knockout source for their 'uniqueName' binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers['uniqueName'] = {
    'init': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        if (valueAccessor()) {
            element.name = "ko_unique_" + (++ko.bindingHandlers['uniqueName'].currentIndex);

            // Workaround IE 6/7 issue
            // - https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/197
            // - http://www.matts411.com/post/setting_the_name_attribute_in_ie_dom/
            if (ko.utils.isIe6 || ko.utils.isIe7)
                element.mergeAttributes(document.createElement("<input name='" + element.name + "'/>"), false);
        }
    }
};
```

Simply leverage the same mechanism for merging attributes and this will have the same effect as changing the name attribute but in an IE6\7 friendly way.