# How to pass selected option values into as a textfield's name attribute?

Tags: php, javascript, html

For eg I have this code.

```
Select one of your preferred contact methods:
<p><br>
<select name="contactmethod">
<option value="phonenohome">Home No</option>
<option value="phonenowork">Work No</option>
<option value="mobileno">Mobile No</option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="">
```

What I want to do here is to when one of the dropdownlist value is selected for eg "mobileno", I want this "mobileno" value to be transferred as a textfield's name attribute (as shown at the bottom of the code).  Does that make sense?

I thought a simple Javascript or PHP code might do just the trick.  I'm not so sure this can be done.  What do you think?

Comment: And what exactly are you having problems with? Getting a reference to the elements? Retrieving the selected value? Setting the `name` attribute/property?

Comment: you mean change the name attribute of input text...

Comment: @Sudhir:You're right. I'm trying to assign the selected contactmethod value as a name attribute of the input text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using javascript jQuery framework, assuming input has a `id` as `contact_type`

```
$('select').change(function(){
  $('#contact_type').attr('name', $('select').val());
});
```

Comment: I tried this.  But it doesn't appear to be working.  When checking the source code via my Google Chrome browser, my input field's name attribute did not change.

Comment: Well it is a working code, I tried for a sample page before posting here. You may have to change the id of text field and give a proper id to the select box field.

Comment: I see.  It should work.  Just that when I checked the frame source of the demo above, the contact_type's name attribute did not change on the fly.. My concern is if I were to post this text input's phone number into another page, how would I be able to determine which contact type it takes when name attribute is still missing before inserting into a table in Access database?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with simple js function ...

```
function set_val(){
    document.getElementByName('contactmethod').value = document.getElementByName('text_box_name').value;
}
```

you need to call this function onchange event of select box.

I think It should work for you..

Comment: You got it somehow wrong. When the selected option changes, the `name` attribute of the `input` field should be set to the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select one of your preferred contact methods:
<p><br>
<select name="contactmethod" id="contactmethod">
<option value="phonenohome">Home No</option>
<option value="phonenowork">Work No</option>
<option value="mobileno">Mobile No</option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="selectedmethod" id="selectedmethod" value="">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var select = document.getElementById('contactmethod');
    var input = document.getElementById('selectedmethod');
    select.onchange = function(){
        input.name = this.value;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Tried this.  But my input field's name attribute did not change ie it still retain "selectedmethod" as the original value.

Comment: @AW-GWTF899 It does change the name attribute to whatever is selected.  I tested it in Firefox, Internet Explorer 8/9, Opera, and Google Chrome.  Note that IE's Developer Tools don't automatically reflect changes to the code.  You have to click the refresh button in the Developer Tools window/pane.  That only refreshes the view of the code, not the page.  IE7 behaves a little differently, though.  It adds a `submitName` property.  More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2105980/166560).

Comment: If that is the case, why don't you create hidden input field and change the value of that on change of select tag value? Or if the select tag value is accessible in controller, why don't you use the same?

Comment: My Biggest apologies to you too.  I finally got your code working now!  It was because I made several typos with my code after copying everbody's code blindly, here and there...  Sorry! :p