# javascript setAttribute("name",newname) not change textbox's name it create submitName

Tags: javascript, html

i use this function to create a new row in table

```
   function addRow(obj) 
    {
            var table = document.getElementById("table2");
            var rowCount = table.rows.length-1;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
            var nowrownum = table.rows.length-1;        
            var colCount = table.rows[2].cells.length;
            for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[2].cells[i].innerHTML;
                newcell.style.cssText = table.rows[2].cells[i].style.cssText;

//Here is problem
                newcell.childNodes[0].setAttribute("name",table.rows[2].cells[i].childNodes[0].getAttribute("name")+nowrownum);
//End here                 
                newcell.childNodes[0].id    = table.rows[2].cells[i].childNodes[0].id+nowrownum;
                switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type)  
                {
                    case "text":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                            break;
                }
            }
            obj.style.visibility = "hidden"; //to hide current button
    }
```

Here is my html code

```
  <form name=form id=form  method=POST target="frametemp">
    <table name ="table2" id="table2" border="1"  align="Center">
     <tr>
         <th>Head1</th>
         <th>Head2</th>
         <th>Head3</th>
         <th>Head4</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>xxxxx</td>
         <td><input type="text" id="edit_0"   name="edit_0" ></td>
         <td>yyyy</td>
         <td><input id="add_bt_0" onclick="JavaScript : addRow(this);" name="add_bt_0" value="addrow" type="button" ></td>
     </tr>
```

after row is add i check the page from ie developer tool

```
<td><input type="text" id="edit_1"   name="edit_0" submitName="edit_1" ></td>
<td><input id="add_bt_1" onclick="JavaScript : addRow(this);" name="add_bt_0" submitName="add_bt_1" value="addrow" type="button" ></td>
```

the name attribute does not change but it create submitName.

how can i make name attribute change.
my target brower is IE 7++(now i use ie 9)

Answer (score 1):

How you change the id ..?? Use the same code to change the attribute name .. I mean

```
newcell.childNodes[0].name = table.rows[2].cells[i].childNodes[0].name + nowrownum;
```

Comment: Because getAttribute and setAttribute are broken in Internet Explorer .. Mostly its better to avoid usind these functions

Comment: i use this
`newcell.childNodes[0].id    = table.rows[2].cells[i].childNodes[0].id+nowrownum;`
to set id

Comment: i have try `newcell.childNodes[0].name  = table.rows[2].cells[i].childNodes[0].name+nowrownum;` but the result is same name is not change submitName are create

Comment: Have a look on this link and use as per the browser version ..http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#attributes

Comment: Have a look on this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105815/weird-behaviour-of-iframe-name-attribute-set-by-jquery-in-ie.. You got struck with this F***inG IE

Comment: Thank, could you suggest me what method i should replace getAttribute and setAttribute.

Comment: You should go for innerHTML

Comment: could you give me an example by use innerHTML.

Answer (score 1):

They fixed this in IE8. In previous versions, you need to include the name when you call createElement. From MSDN:

> Internet Explorer 8 and later can set the NAME attribute at run time
>   on elements dynamically created with the IHTMLDocument2::createElement
>   method. To create an element with a NAME attribute in earlier versions
>   of Internet Explorer, include the attribute and its value when using
>   the IHTMLDocument2::createElement method.

Here is the example from MSDN:

```
var newRadioButton = document.createElement("<INPUT TYPE='RADIO' NAME='RADIOTEST'VALUE='First Choice'>")
```