# JavaScript: unable to modify name attribute in java script in IE browser

Tags: javascript

When ever i try changing the value of "name" attribute, it is creating a new attribute "submitName" in InternetExplorer.

`<input id="input1" type="text" name="userName">`

Example: `document.getElementById("input1").name = "userNameInput";`

In DOM it is creating as :  `<input id="input1" type="text" name="firstInput" submitName="userNameInput">`

Note: Even i used setAttribute(), That is also not working for me.

What i want is: `<input id="input1" type="text" name="userNameInput">`

Please help me on modifying the name attribute.

Comment: Why dont you change the name in the HTML template?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that.

Comment: Open your html file and replace the name.

Comment: What IE version are you using in that case ?

Comment: This was an issue until Internet Explorer 8. Which version are you running your script in? [Below Internet Explorer 8 one could not change the `name` after the element was appened to the dom.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562956/javascript-setattributename-newname-not-change-textboxs-name-it-create-subm)

Comment: How looks your html code? Wich version of IE do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following JS code for doing that. It will work on all browsers.

```
var field = document.getElementById("input1");
field.setAttribute("name", "userNameInput");
```

The below code is working fine on Internet Explorer. I checked it.

```
<input id="input1" type="text" name="userName">
<script>
document.getElementById("input1").name = "userNameInput";
</script>
```

Comment: I tried that as well. But that is also not working.