# jQuery clone problem

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, clone

I am trying to clone a div and change the names of the input fields in this div.
It works great for most of the browsers but IE 7 does not change the name attribute of the input fields.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/iduro/7

HTML

```
<body>
  <pre></pre>
  <div><input value="Hello World" name="test"></div>
</body>
```

JS

```
var lastRow = $("body div:last"),
    newRow  = lastRow.clone(true)
              .show()
              .insertAfter(lastRow);

newRow.find('input').attr("name","test2");

$("pre").text( newRow[0].innerHTML );
```

Results:

Firefox: (works)
 `<input value="Hello World" name="test2">`

IE8 (works) 
`<INPUT value="Hello World" name=test2 jQuery1273063250500="4">`

IE7 (bug): 
`<INPUT value="Hello World" name=test jQuery1273063303968="4">`

As you see the name of IE7 does not change to test2.

Is there any obvious reason or work around?

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094618/changing-name-attr-of-cloned-input-element-in-jquery-doesnt-work-in-ie6-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could fix it for now.
As long as an input field is not attached to the dom you can change the name and the radio buttons work properly again.

```
// Old Code
 $("div:last").clone(true).children("input").attr("name","newName");

// New Code
 $("div:last").clone(true).children("input").fixCloneBug ("newName");
```

To lower the execution time only the jQuery Events, the className and the type attribute are copied.

fixCloneBug Method:

```
(function( $ )
{


    if ( ! $.browser.msie || parseInt( $.browser.version ) > 7 )
        // NO FIX FOR IE 7+ FF WEBKIT
        $.fn.fixCloneBug = function( newName ){ return this.attr( "name", newName ) };
    else
        // FIX IE 5-7
        $.fn.fixCloneBug = function( newName )
        {
            var $cloned = $();

            this.each(function( )
            {
                    /* -._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._

                       Create a new element with className and jQuery events of the buggy element

                    */          

                    var     $elem    = $(this),

                            $newElem = $(document.createElement( $elem.attr('tagName') ));

                            // USE SAME TYPE

                    $newElem.attr('type', $elem.attr('type') );


                            // SET NAME
                    $newElem.attr('name', this.name );
                    $newElem.attr('name', newName );

                            // ADD TO DOM

                    $newElem.insertBefore( $elem );

                            // CLONE EVENTS
                    $newElem.data( "events", $elem.data("events") );

                            // CLASS NAME
                    $newElem.attr('className', this.className );

                    /* -._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._.-._

                       Delete buggy element 

                    */

                    $elem.remove();


                    // Add to result
                    $cloned.push($newElem);
            })

            return $cloned;

        }

}(jQuery));
```

Maybe you think `$newElem.attr('name', this.name );` is useless however it allows me to use a jQuery 1.4 feature:

`.fixCloneBug (function(i,oldname){ return oldname+"_new" })`

Answer (score 1):

try this ( raw code)

```
$(some_cloned_element).each(function(i, elem){
    var newName = "yay_i_love_my_new_name";
    if ($.browser.msie === true){ // evil browser sniffing *cries*
        $(elem).replaceWith(document.createElement(
            this.outerHTML.replace(/name=\w+/ig, 'name='+newName+'_'+i)
        ));
    } else {
        $(elem).attr('name',newName+'_'+i);
    }
    $("body").append(some_cloned_element);
});
```

check when **i=50** and then *break/exit*

**better way :** use name as array like `name=picture[]`

[Refernece](http://www.danconnor.com/dynamic-name-input-attributes-with-ie-and-jquery-clones.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you pan on accessing these as a set when the form is posted then there is no need to change the name - just dont put a value within the brackets and it will be incremented for you when you grab the array on the server side:

`<input name="test[]" />`

If you need to be able to access each one by index from js you can just use `get` on the appropriate collection returned by a selector. Or you can assign ID attributes like `test_1`.

Comment: I try to clone a row of radio buttons.
However as changing the name does not work the user can only choose one radio button for both rows instead of two.

Comment: @prodigtalson +1. Tried this when running into the same solution and solved my issue. I only used text inputs and select statements, so radio issues as mentioned above may still occur.

Comment: Useful info, but -1 because this doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution for Radio button is :

```
$("div:last").find("radio").each(function(){
     var name="someNewName";
     var id="someNewId";
    if (!$.browser.msie || parseInt($.browser.version) > 7) {
      this.name = name;
      this.id=id;
    }
    else {
      (this).attr("outerHTML", "<input type=radio id=" + id + " name=" + name + " />");  
    }
});
```

*This will alter the **outerHTML** of the element so that the HTML for the element(radio button) is overwritten. The same solution can be applied for : find("input") / find("checkbox") for the other controls too.*