# dynamically renaming form elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, dom

I have a table inside a form, which is populated with various input boxes. I have written various JavaScript functions that will allow the user to add or remove a row from the table, and will also dynamically rename the element names that come after where the user has entered the row (if that makes sense - hopefully my code will explain what I'm trying to do).

This works in IE9, Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE7 (which a lot of people in my organization who are still on XP currently use).

The code isn't the most elegant thing I've ever written, but I need to fix this before demoing it in front of people tomorrow! (So I'm willing to consider anything, even if it's a quick and dirty fix at this point!)

Thanks!

```
for (var e = 0; e < editForm.elements.length; e++) {
    // Increment 'add row' buttons so that they add underneath the correct row
    if (editForm.elements[e].name.length >= 4) {
        if (editForm.elements[e].name.substr(0, 4) == 'add_') {
            stringPos = editForm.elements[e].name.indexOf('_');
            currentQuestionNumber = editForm.elements[e].name.substr(stringPos + 1);
            if (currentQuestionNumber > pos) {
                editForm.elements[e].name = 'add_' + (parseInt(currentQuestionNumber) + 1);
                editForm.elements[e].id = 'add_' + (parseInt(currentQuestionNumber) + 1);
                editForm.elements[e].setAttribute("onclick", "addRow(" + (parseInt(currentQuestionNumber) + 1) + ");");
            }
        }
    }
```

In place of...

```
editForm.elements[e].name = 'add_' + (parseInt(currentQuestionNumber) + 1);
```

...I have also used...

```
editForm.elements[e].setAttribute("name", "add_" + (parseInt(currentQuestionNumber) + 1));
```

...but this doesn't work in IE7 either. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What about leaving the names alone and compiling them as an array server side, à la PHP's [form handling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays)? I've done this myself by formatting the submitted data as XML before submission.

Comment: You don't need both `if`'s, since the second condition can only be true if the first is as well, making the first redundant. I'm surprised this worked at all cross-browser, since you're setting the click event using `setAttribute` which doesn't work in all IE versions. Maybe just have a "global" counter that increments on every row addition, then you won't have to do all this inline string parsing...

Comment: Can we just set an embargo on `get/set/removeAttribute`? They're more trouble than they're worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the elements you're changing names have been dynamically created, you may be hitting an IE6/7 bug. There's a pointer to a possible workaround to the [`setAttribute` bug](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2008/03/bug-240-setattribute-name-is-half.html) on the Web Bug Track blog. You may also find the answers to ["Changing name attr of cloned input element in jQuery doesn't work in IE6/7"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2094618/851811) useful.