# Clone a <tr> and also increment the name attribute of elements inside <td> by 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've to implement a 'Add New Row' feature in a form. The structure of the form is something like:

```
<table>
<tr>
     <td><input type="text" name="v1[label]" /></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="v1[observation]" /></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="v1[remarks]" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td><input type="text" name="v2[label]" /></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="v2[observation]" /></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="v2[remarks]" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
       <input type="button" id="addrow" value="Add One More Row">&nbsp;
       <input type="submit" name="proceed" value="Submit" />
    </td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

As seen, with each row, there is an increase in `v[]` number. v1, v2..and so on

**WHAT I'M LOOKING FOR**

When 'Add One More Row' button is clicked, the following things should happen

- A new row gets inserted just above the last row (the row with
  buttons)
- The name attribute value increases by 1 (i.e. v2[label] becomes
  v3[label], v2[observation] becomes v3[observation] and so on) in that
  row

**WHAT I TRIED**

The closest I came to was using `jQuery's` `clone()`. This does add the row perfectly. But I'm finding it difficult to find a way to increase the value of the name attribute by 1 each time  the button is clicked.

**jQUERY BEING USED CURRENTLY**

```
$('input:button[id="addrow"]').click(function(){

   var secondlast = $('table tr:last').prev('tr');
   secondlast.clone().insertBefore(secondlast);

});
```

If I click the button two times, I'm getting the following HTML added

```
<tr>
     <td><input type="text" name="v2[label]" /></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="v2[observation]" /></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="v2[remarks]" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
     <td><input type="text" name="v2[label]" /></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="v2[observation]" /></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="v2[remarks]" /></td>
</tr>
```

So a row is being added, but the name attribute remains at v2, whereas it should be v3 and v4 for the third and fourth row. I understand `clone()` can't do that and that is why I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: Have you tried processing the clone before inserting it? With something like, for example, `secondlast.clone().each('input')` , parsing the name and replacing the number?

Comment: Hmm..that makes sense. I'll try and see if I can achieve that

Comment: @Eregrith I'm crystal clear with the logic, but finding it hard to convert that into programming syntax :(

Comment: You can just manipulate the attribute and increment it based on how many table rows there are at point of event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('input:button[id="addrow"]').click(function(){
    var secondlast = $('table tr:last').prev('tr');
    var newClone = secondlast.clone();
    // find all the inputs within your new clone and for each one of those
    newClone.find('input').each(function() {
        var currentNameAttr = $(this).attr('name'); // get the current name attribute
        // construct a new name attribute using regular expressions
        // the match is divided into three groups (indicated by parentheses)
        // p1 will be 'v', p2 will be the number, p3 will be the remainder of the string
        var newNameAttr = currentNameAttr.replace(/^(v)(\d+)(.*)$/, function(match, p1, p2, p3) {
            return p1+(parseInt(p2)+1)+p3;
        });
        $(this).attr('name', newNameAttr);   // set the incremented name attribute 
    });
    // insert after is I assume what you want
    newClone.insertAfter(secondlast);
});
```

**Edit**

```
// you could also simply increment any digit you find as Batman indicated
var newNameAttr = currentNameAttr.replace(/\d+/, function(match) {
    return (parseInt(match)+1);
});
```

Comment: This works as intended. Just give me a second to play around with it. I also have to test it with select boxes

Comment: Yep. Works perfectly as intended. I just replaced `newClone.find('input').each(function()` with `newClone.find('input, select').each(function()`. +1 and accepting as answer. Also appreciate the comments supplied with your code xD

Comment: +1 for the elegance in the solution. However, confirm one huge caveat: [Changing name attr of cloned input element in jQuery doesn’t work in IE6/7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2094618/122005)?

Comment: @chridam Thanks, did not know IE6/7 didn't let you dynamically update the name attribute.

Comment: @cbayram No worries. I suppose the OP could add the `mergeAttributes` fix if `($.browser.msie === true)` becomes a real issue

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send the data in those inputs to a server, it will be hard to determine how many v* you have to take... Instead, I suggest you use [] to add lines in the arrays.

Your HTML would look like that:

```
<table>
<tr>
     <td><input type="text" name="v[label][]" /></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="v[observation][]" /></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="v[remarks][]" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td><input type="text" name="v[label][]" /></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="v[observation][]" /></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="v[remarks][]" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
       <input type="button" id="addrow" value="Add One More Row">&nbsp;
       <input type="submit" name="proceed" value="Submit" />
    </td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

The post variable will be unique: `v` and it will be easy to loop through it to grab the data, here is a PHP exemple.

```
foreach($_POST['v']['label'] as $k=>$v){
    $_POST['v']['label'][$k]; // label
    $_POST['v']['observation'][$k]; // label
    $_POST['v']['remarks'][$k]; // label
}
```

This allows for an unlimited number of inputs, no processing and reformatting of the names for each clone and easier to use.

Comment: Actually the reason I want to increment the value by 1 each time is because I wish to process the form in a similar way listed by you. I'll keep this one as the last option if nothing comes up